# Set an enum to its default value

Tags: c#, enums, default-value, value-type

I'm sure this is fairly trivial but I can't get it right.

```
public static string DoSomething(this Enum value)
 {
     if (!Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value))
     {
         // not a valid value, assume default value
         value = default(value.GetType()); 
     }

     // ... do some other stuff
 }
```

The line `value = default(value.GetType());` doesn't compile, but hopefully you can see what I'm attempting. I need to set the Enum param to the default value of it's own type.

Comment: How can you even call this method without the 'value' being defined in the enum of the same type as 'value'?

Comment: @Paw, that's the way enum works. You can store any int value in an int enum, whether it's defined or not.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet, I'm just trying to understand what you're trying to do. If you want to convert an int to an enum or maybe a string to an enum?

Comment: no I'm querying the FieldInfo on the enum, which obviously throws an exception if the enum isn't defined. It makes sense I think to use the "default" FieldInfo in this case.

Comment: ...and the reason the enum value might not be defined is because our database is full of crap unfortunately :)

Comment: This is actually a very interesting question. Unfortunately, most answers apparently understood it wrong. It might have helped to choose a better name than `DoSomething`.

Comment: @Konrad, point taken. For obvious reasons I try to post simplified examples which obfuscate the exact purpose of the code, and it often results in people misunderstanding or telling me that what I'm doing doesn't make any sense. Perhaps I could have given a little more detail here, but I thought the specific problem was fairly apparent from the example.

Comment: I think you may be considering "default value" to mean something different to what the compiler will use as a default for enumerations. The default value for an enumeration is always zero, even if there is no defined zero-value in your enum. From the spec "The default value of an enum E is the value produced by the expression (E)0."

Comment: Hmmm, re-reading the question, maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet - I'm not sure you are asking the right question here.  Some of the provided answers give you a default enum (with value 0) as per CLR rules which may or may not be a defined enum - thus leaving you in the same boat as before.  I would argue that the 'default' that you want is really an arbitrarily defined enum value that differs for each enum definition.  So either you have to decorate your enum definition to mark that special value or you have to pass that special value into your DoSomething routine. This is because the CLR system does not know your intent

Answer (score 5):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here, but a version of the 'default' line which does compile is this:

```
 value = (Enum)Enum.GetValues(value.GetType()).GetValue(0);
```

Or, even cleaner (from Paw, in the comments, thanks):

```
 value = (Enum) Enum.ToObject(value.GetType(), 0);
```

This second version does only work properly if you know the enum's first element has a value of zero.

Comment: or
value = (Enum) Enum.ToObject(value.GetType(), 0);

Comment: @paw What if you're using this: `enum Foo{a=1,b=2}`? +1 to Will though, it looks pretty robust

Comment: @Paw: No. 0 isn’t a defined value for all enums.

Comment: @Konrad: That might be the case, but 0 is the default value for an enum, whether it is defined or not. It's what the compiler initializes enum variables to and one of the reasons why there is an FxCop error regarding a zero-value in enum definitions. From the spec, "The default value of an enum E is the value produced by the expression (E)0."

Comment: @Konrad: I'm not so sure. They don't know the enumeration type and just setting value to zero wouldn't work without a cast, but they can't cast because they don't have the type.

Comment: @Jeff, yes that's correct. It would be cooler to do it the 'proper' way, but in my case I don't care too much as all my enums have a `NotSet = 0` value anyway. I got stuck because `value = 0` doesn't work without a cast as you commented.

Answer (score 2):

You actually could do what [Paw is suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096431/set-an-enum-to-its-default-value/4096619#4096619), even with a generic constraint, if you could move this method to its own class:

```
public abstract class Helper<T>
{
    public static string DoSomething<TEnum>(TEnum value) where TEnum: struct, T
    {
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), value))
        {
            value = default(TEnum);
        }

        // ... do some other stuff

        // just to get code to compile
        return value.ToString();
    }
}

public class EnumHelper : Helper<Enum> { }
```

Then you would do, for example:

```
MyEnum x = MyEnum.SomeValue;
MyEnum y = (MyEnum)100; // Let's say this is undefined.

EnumHelper.DoSomething(x); // generic type of MyEnum can be inferred
EnumHelper.DoSomething(y); // same here
```

As Konrad Rudolph points out in a comment, `default(TEnum)` in the above code will evaluate to 0, regardless of whether or not a value is defined for 0 for the given `TEnum` type. If that's not what you want, [Will's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096431/set-an-enum-to-its-default-value/4096649#4096649) provides certainly the easiest way of getting the first *defined* value (`(TEnum)Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).GetValue(0)`).

On the other hand, if you want to take this to the **extreme**, and cache the result so that you don't always have to box it, you could do that:

```
public abstract class Helper<T>
{
    static Dictionary<Type, T> s_defaults = new Dictionary<Type, T>();

    public static string DoSomething<TEnum>(TEnum value) where TEnum: struct, T
    {
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), value))
        {
            value = GetDefault<TEnum>();
        }

        // ... do some other stuff

        // just to get code to compile
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public static TEnum GetDefault<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, T
    {
        T definedDefault;
        if (!s_defaults.TryGetValue(typeof(TEnum), out definedDefault))
        {
            // This is the only time you'll have to box the defined default.
            definedDefault = (T)Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).GetValue(0);
            s_defaults[typeof(TEnum)] = definedDefault;
        }

        // Every subsequent call to GetDefault on the same TEnum type
        // will unbox the same object.
        return (TEnum)definedDefault;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Konrad: That *may* be because I had a typo in it (`TEnumvalue`—no space). Also I didn't include a return value. I'd be curious to know if it does compile for Mono now that I updated the example.

Comment: I’d already corrected that, didn’t help. Weirdly, it now compiles (+1, elegant hack!) – but it has the same problem as the other solutions, namely that `default` really returns `0` which may be an undefined value in the actual enum and thus isn’t the right result. There’s the added problem that your solution no longer works as an extension method.

Comment: @Konrad: Yeah, I realized that too shortly after posting (tested on an enum whose first defined value is 1), but I felt it was worth mentioning since it seems *one* of things the OP was trying to do was simply write `default(TEnum)`.

Answer (score 1):

`Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConsoleColor))` seems to work

Comment: You need a hard cast for this. (ConsoleColor)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConsoleColor))

Comment: @Paw, how would you do that in fear's example (with a dynamic type)

Comment: you can't, that's why I don't think it will work with Activator.

Answer (score -1):

`Enum` by default have its `first value` as `default value`

Comment: again, how does this solve my problem? (and it's not even technically correct i don't think)

Comment: -1: Sorry, but the default value for every enum is 0, even if 0 is an invalid value for the enum. Try `enum MyEnum { M1 = -1, M2 = 1 }; MyEnum e = default(MyEnum); ... Console.WriteLine("{0}", e);` Writes `0`

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought about making it a generic method?

```
public static string DoSomething<T>(Enum value)
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), value))
    {
        value = (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), 0);
    }
    // ... do some other stuff
}
```

The caller of the method should know the type.

Comment: The `where T : enum` doesn’t exist in C#. :-( That’s the whole problem here.

Comment: Would still work though, without the 'where'. You'd just need try/catch to make sure your cast dosn't blow up. I'd throw a new exception to the caller if T wasn't an enum.

Comment: So, if he doesn't know what the enum type is, how does he declare T?

Comment: @Caspar, eeh, that's why I wrote "The caller of the method should know the type". If caller dosn't then this of course won't work.